# iframe for intro splash message time interval before webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Hi I want to create simple splash screen banner with Iframe and message to be displayed for a second or two before the main web page content loads.

this is what I have at the moment:

```
    //greetings iframe
        echo '<iframe scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true" name="maingreet" id="maingreet" style="width:100%;height:90%;"><img src="../images/greetings.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/></iframe>
            <script>setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("maingreet").innerHTML="";},1500);</script>';

//main web page starts here
    include_once("../xxx/_header.php");

    include("../xxx/_fx_cats.php");
    include '_arch.php';
    ...
```

I am not sure how/where to put the javascript set timeout function and how to redirect to the main web page part

Answer (score 0):

Put your greetings iframe in a div ('splash') and wrap your main site in another div ('container') with `display:none`.  Then something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#splash').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
      $('#container').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');
 });
```

Change the numbers to suit your timing.